# Dual of the dual of a semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, semidefinite-programming

The dual of the dual of an SDP primal looks identical to the primal problem (algebraically). Then, why is it that in optimization books it is stated that the dual of the dual is a lower bound to the primal problem?

(By algebraically, I mean when I take the dual of the dual it gives me the same problem as the original primal problem. So, the solutions of the two, if they exist, must be the same. Correct?)

Comment: You're aware that strong duality doesn't always hold for SDP, right?  What happens when you take the dual of the dual of a problem for which strong duality doesn't hold?

Comment: Why do they look algebraically the same then? I think I have a hard time understanding the concept of strong duality. From what I understand, the strong duality says that the primal and dual are attained and equal if the Slater holds. I don't see how this relates to my question; unless you're referring to the case of primal solution going to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Teodorism do you have a reference for "the dual of the dual is a lower bound to the primal problem"? It may refer to a nonconvex problem, not to a semidefinite optimization problem.

Comment: Without an exact quote it's difficult to respond to this question.  Could you link to your source or provide a citation?

Comment: Are you aware that there are examples of primal-dual pairs of SDP's that have different optimal objective values?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes. I believe, that's why one has to check Slater to ensure strong duality holds.

Comment: I think the reason that applying weak duality twice does not give strong duality is that both the weak dualities give the same result, since once your primal-dual problem is a max in primal -min in dual problem and the other time it is min in primal and max in dual